# What's the difference in the following code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stud
{
    int age;
    struct stud *next;
};

typedef struct stud node;

node *createlist();
void main()
{
    node *head;

    head = createlist();
}

node *createlist()
{

    node *head, *p;

    head = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));

    int i, n;

    printf("Enter the number of elements\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            p = head;
        }
        else
        {
            p->next = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
            p = p->next;
        }
        p->age = i;             /* This line here - what happens with (*p).age = i; or
                                   &p->age = i; */
    }

    p->next = NULL;
    return head;
}
```

What's the difference if I replace the code highlighted by the comment with:

```
(*p).age = i;
```

and

```
&p->age = i;
```

Basically I'm creating a Linked list of the structure stud and I'm trying to initialize some values to it's members.

Comment: Well, one will compile, and the other will not. What do you actually want to do? Trial and error isn't the way forward.

Comment: Is your real question just what is the difference between `(*p).age` and `p->age`? What does it have to do with all the code that you are posting? Why can't you condense your question into a decent question title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current code is

```
p->age = i;
```

---

That is identical to

```
(*p).age = i;
```

On the other hand,

```
&p->age = i;
```

is a compilation error.

Because `->` has a higher precedence than `&`, that is parsed as

```
&(p->age) = i;
```

And you cannot assign an `int` to an `int*`, not to mention that fact that `&(p->age)` is not an lvalue.

Answer (score -1):

Both will access the structure member `age`.

But `&p->age = i;` will cause compile time error.
`->` has the higher precedence that unary `&` operator, so compiler interprets it as

```
&(p->age) = i;
```

As `&` operator results in r-value, `&(p->age)` will become an r-value.
As Standard says:

> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

This statement will cause compile time error.

Comment: I again ask the downvoter, please leave your comment.